# How do I filter an array while excluding specific conditions?

Tags: javascript

I have button that I’m disabling by reading an array and checking its properties.

My array looks like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {id: ‘1’, name: ‘SOME_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
  {id: ‘2’, name: ‘THIS_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
  {id: ‘3’, name: ‘OTHER_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
  {id: ‘4’, name: ‘EVERY_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
];
```

My current logic to disable/enable this button looks like this:

```js
arr.filter((item) => item.indexOf(‘THING’) > -1)
   .every((item) => item.status === ‘AGREED’)
```

Now my requirements have changed. I want to enable/disable the button in the same way, but I want to **EXCLUDE** specific elements from this array. For example, I want to exclude these two items:

```js
{id: ‘2’, name: ‘THIS_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
{id: ‘3’, name: ‘OTHER_THING’, status: ‘AGREED’},
```

Using my logic, how do I filter my array while EXCLUDING these two?

I realize I can just try to delete these specific items but I was wondering if there was potentially a cleaner way to do that without explicit deletion.

Comment: just add the conditions to the filter

Comment: Did you extent prototype of object? Object doesn't implement indexOf() by default,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude a list of items by always assuming the given key/value pair is true regardless of the value

```
const exclusionList = ['THIS_THING', 'OTHER_THING'];

arr.filter((item) => item.indexOf(‘THING’) > -1)
   .every((item) => item.status === ‘AGREED’ || exclusionList.includes(item.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please add your **keyName(name)** Where you using **indexOf**

```
let arr = [
      {id: '1', name: 'SOME_THING', status: 'AGREED'},
      {id: '2', name: 'THIS_THING', status: 'AGREED'},
      {id: '3', name: 'OTHER_THING', status: 'AGREED'},
      {id: '4', name: 'EVERY_THING', status: 'AGREED'},
      
    ]; 
    const list = ['THIS_THING', 'OTHER_THING'];
    console.log(arr.filter((item) => item.name.indexOf(‘THING’) > -1).every((user) => user.status === 'AGREED' || list.some(user.name)))
```